# pycharmでdockerにremoteで接続する際のユーザー指定について

Tags: python, docker

pycharmのremote機能で、dockerのコンテナに接続して作業する際の、実行ユーザーの指定方法がわからず困っております。。

rootユーザーではなく、アプリケーション作成用ユーザーを指定してpycharmで作業がしたいのですが、もしご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教授頂けませんでしょうか。

prereferenceの中を全部開いてみたのですが、ちょっとわからず。。
どうぞ宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: dockerコマンドでどのようなコマンドを実行するイメージでしょうか？（普段dockerでroot以外のユーザーを作って作業していないので、PyCharmでできるかどうか気にしたことがありませんでした）

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。
具体的には、https://hub.docker.com/r/mathewlee11/pycaffe/　のimageをpullしまして、こちらのpycaffeユーザーのインタプリタを利用してpycharm上でコーディングしたいと考えております。
現在は、もしかしたら、イメージの元となるDockerFileに対して何か工夫をしないといけないのかも？と思い、調べてみています。